# Filtering data doing a lookup with comma separate values

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, filter, slice

I have the following data frame that represents the employee number, the department they are and their role code in the company that can be "1" or "2". On the column "Department Name" you can either have the department the employee has their role (naming convention being "XX:Dept Name" where XX is the country code) or, in some cases, it appears a group of Departments, separate by comma "," with the role the employee have in those departments. It would look something like this:

```
  Department Name                Employee Number      Role Code   
0  AU:Dept1                         1000                     1
1  AU:Dept1, AU:Dept3               1000                     2
2  AU:Dept7                         1000                     1
3  CZ:Dept3                         1001                     2
4  CZ:Dept4, CZ:Dept6, CZ:Dept7     1001                     2
5  CZ:Dept4                         1001                     1 
6  PL:Dept1                         1002                     2
7  PL:Dept2, PL:Dept1               1002                     1
8  PL:Dept3                         1002                     2
9  SG:Dept1                         1003                     1
10 SG:Dept1                         1003                     2
11 SG:Dept2                         1003                     2
```

Employees can have either only Role 1 OR Role 2 in each unique department name so I need to create a code that would return all conflicted rows where the employee is appearing to have both Role 1 AND Role 2 in the same department. That would be the output:

```
  Department Name                Employee Number      Role Code   
0  AU:Dept1                         1000                     1
1  AU:Dept1, AU:Dept3               1000                     2
4  CZ:Dept4, CZ:Dept6, CZ:Dept7     1001                     2
5  CZ:Dept4                         1001                     1 
6  PL:Dept1                         1002                     2
7  PL:Dept2, PL:Dept1               1002                     1
9  SG:Dept1                         1003                     1
10 SG:Dept1                         1003                     2
```

What would be the best way to do this filter?

Comment: Have you tried it? Post code. We can help with specific problems in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I was on vacation, accepted the answer already, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
df['both_role'] = df.groupby('Employee Number')['Role Code'].isin([1]).astype(int) * df.groupby('Employee Number')['Role Code'].isin([2]).astype(int) 

df[df.both_role == 1]
```

You can groupby using Employee Number and check if Role Code contains 1 and 2 for each user. If it contains both 1 and 2 then you can filter dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try splitting the Department Name, then `groupby` on `['Employee', 'Name']` to find out which employees have two roles with `nunique`:

```
(df.assign(Name=df['Department Name'].str.split(', '))
   .explode('Name')
   .loc[lambda x:x.groupby(['Employee Number','Name'])
                 ['Role Code'].transform('nunique') ==2 ]
   .drop('Name', axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
                 Department Name  Employee Number  Role Code
0                       AU:Dept1             1000          1
1             AU:Dept1, AU:Dept3             1000          2
4   CZ:Dept4, CZ:Dept6, CZ:Dept7             1001          2
5                       CZ:Dept4             1001          1
6                       PL:Dept1             1002          2
7             PL:Dept2, PL:Dept1             1002          1
9                       SG:Dept1             1003          1
10                      SG:Dept1             1003          2
```